# Confused about arrow functions

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

would you please tell me what's wrong with snippet 1? My expected output for obj.discover() is 3. How can't I bind `this` to an arrow function method of an object?

```
'use strict'

// Snippet 1
var obj = {
  data: 3,
  discover: () => {
    return this.data
  }
}
obj.discover() // -> undefined 
obj.discover.bind(obj)() // undefined

// but if I don't use the arrow notation, everything works
// Snippet 2
var obj2 = {
  data: 3,
  discover: function(){
    return this.data
  }
}
obj2.discover() // -> 3
```

Comment: Arrow functions don't have their own `this`, use regular functions for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions are not just a syntactic sugar but differ in some behaviour as well. In arrow functions, `this` always point to the object at which it was pointing at the time of function definition.

Comment: Worth also pointing out that in the OPs case, `this` is the global object when `discover` is created in `obj`.  If it were an object created using `new` etc, it'd be fine to use `this` in an arrow function in that way.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Thank you for your thorough explanation.

Comment: @dejavu_cmd_delt: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions don't allow for binding. Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) reference on MDN:

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function
>   expressions and **does not bind its own this**, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.

Arrow function will resolve the `this` to its lexical scope.

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions aren't the same as normal functions and shouldn't be used as object methods.  They don't bind 'this', among other things. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions